# align view on top and buttons in bottom

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I need to achieve the following view

[image]

I tried using constraint layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/segmentedButton">
     </FrameLayout>

     <Buttons
                android:id="@+id/segmentedButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
     </Buttons>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It works well when there are many items, but when there are just 2-3, it shows them in the middle. 
Also, I tried using LinearLayout but no luck.

Comment: you want to show the items on top, if there are 2 or 3 ?

Comment: use a vertical linear layout, or relative layout with layout_below property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `RelativeLayout`too to get your desired results. By using the below code you can show the items on top if they are 2 or 3 left.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/segmentedButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/segmentedButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with linear layout, weight property should push the button to align at the end of parent

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
       >
    </FrameLayout>

    <Buttons
        android:id="@+id/segmentedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        >
    </Buttons>

</LinearLayout>
```

I supposed here that Buttons stand for a custom Button you made

Answer (score 0):

Just add Top Constraint to your FrameLayout, should fix your issue.

Your final layout will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/segmentedButton"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></FrameLayout>

    <Buttons
        android:id="@+id/segmentedButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"></Buttons>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/segmentedFrame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/segmentedButton"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_scan_edittext">
    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/segmentedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/segmentedFrame"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
    </Button>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```